# Global hotkey with WIN32 API?

Tags: c++, winapi, hwnd, registerhotkey

I've been able to set local hotkeys like this

```
 RegisterHotKey(hwndDlg, 100, MOD_ALT | MOD_CONTROL, 'S');
```

How can I set the hotkey to be global? I want it to be there even when my window is hidden.

Comment: I've been writing Windows apps for nearly 20 years and I didn't know this API call existed - so thanks, and +1.  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved it myself but thanks for your reply
here's what was wrong...

```
ShowWindow(hwndDlg, SW_HIDE);
RegisterHotKey(hwndDlg, 100, MOD_ALT | MOD_CONTROL, 'S');
```

if you register the hotkey first then hide the window... it ignores the hotkey for some reason... oh well.. it's working now :)

Comment: Cool. So it's guaranteed to be global?

Answer (score 8):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx

> hWnd [in, optional]
>
> Type: HWND
>
> <...> If this parameter is NULL, WM_HOTKEY messages are posted to the
> message queue of the calling thread and must be processed in the
> message loop.

That is a better way for registering global hotkeys.

Answer (score 4):

It desn't matter if your window is visible or not. You should not use a hWnd you plan to destory (like a dialog). Create a separate (invisible) window if you have no other suitable window.

Comment: I don't destroy it 
I just hide it like this
ShowWindow(hwndDlg, SW_HIDE);

Answer (score 4):

First you define one or more constants for your hotkeys

```
#define HOTKEY1 1000
#define HOTKEY2 1002
```

Then you register these hot keys

```
RegisterHotKey(NULL, HOTKEY1, MOD_ALT + MOD_SHIFT, 0x53); // ALT+SHIFT+s
RegisterHotKey(NULL, HOTKEY2, MOD_ALT + MOD_SHIFT, 0x51); // ALT+SHIFT+q
```

Finally in the main event loop you monitor these hot keys and respond to them:

if (msg.message == HOTKEY1)
{
switch (LOWORD(msg.wParam))
{
case HOTKEY1:
// do such and such
break;
case HOTKEY2:
// do such and such
break;
}
}